# Python Script ending immediately, no issues with code

Tags: python

So I am using python for the first time in awhile on my laptop (Mac), and im running a test script for something using selenium. There are no issues with the code itself, but the script simply ends immediately without doing anything. Shown below is my terminal:

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-3:Desktop christophergreene$ python3 test.py
Christophers-MacBook-Pro-3:Desktop christophergreene$
```

I'll just drop the full script here, in case it's an issue with selenium:

```
import unittest
import json
from time import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import webbrowser
import time
import requests

URL = 'https://newyork.doverstreetmarket.com/new-items/raffle'
black_XPATH = '//*[@id="field82174636"]/option[2]'
multi_XPATH = '//*[@id="field82174636"]/option[3]'

full_name = 'Chris Greene'
email = 'chris@test.com'
phone = '7817078304'
zip = '10021'

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome() #opens Chrome to complete the task

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(URL) #uses the URL that was generated at the start of the task

        print("Opening raffle...")
        time.sleep(2)


        content_name = driver.find_element_by_id('field82174632')
        content_name.send_keys(full_name)
        print("Name entered...")
        time.sleep(2)

        content_email = driver.find_element_by_id('field82174633')
        content_email.send_keys(email)
        print("Email entered...")
        time.sleep(2)

        content_phone = driver.find_element_by_id('field82174634')
        content_phone.send_keys(phone)
        print("Phone entered...")
        time.sleep(2)

        content_zip = driver.find_element_by_id('field82174635')
        content_zip.send_keys(zip)
        print("Zip code entered...")
        time.sleep(2)

        content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="field82174636"]/option[1]')
        print("Selected White color...")
        time.sleep(2)

        content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="field82174637"]/option[16]')
        print("Selected size 11.5...")
        time.sleep(2)

        submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fsSubmitButton3580291"]')
        submit_button.click()
```

Comment: well it would help if you can show `test.py`

Comment: give us something to debug.... from the command all we can see is this is doing what it should have done

Comment: The issue is that you're creating a class and then not doing anything with it

Comment: Also, just saying, you should probably not post questions containing personal info like a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example), you should call `unittest.main()`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```